# HRESULT 0x80010202 exception in ArcMap closest feature searching by ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, error

My method must return closest feature attribute. But there's a problem, it finds closest feature but returns COM exception HRESULT 0x80010202

```
void selectStreet(IPoint point, IActiveView activeView)
{

..........

if (getLayerByName._GetLayerByName(settings.StreetsLayerName) != null) // Settings1 settings = new Settings1(); settings.StreetsLayerName = "Street"
            {
                var foundLayer = getLayerByName._GetLayerByName(settings.StreetsLayerName);
                IQueryFilterClass qFilter = new IQueryFilterClass () { WhereClause = string.Format("{0} IS NOT NULL", settings.StreetsName) };
                IFeatureCursor featureCursor = (foundLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer).Search(qFilter, false);
                while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
                {
                    double distance = ((IProximityOperator)spatialFilter.Geometry).ReturnDistance(feature.Shape);
                    IProximityOperator prox = spatialFilter.Geometry as IProximityOperator;
                    distance = prox.ReturnDistance(feature.Shape);

                    if (closesToId == -1 || distance < closestDistance)
                    {
                        closesToId = feature.OID;
                        closestDistance = distance;
                        resultFeature = feature;
                        var one = feature.get_Value(feature.Fields.FindField(settings.StreetsName)).ToString(); // StreetsName = "STR_NAME"
                        var two = feature.get_Value(feature.Fields.FindField(settings.StreetsStreetCode)).ToString(); //StreetsStreetCode = "STR_CODE"
                    }
                 }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message); // HRESULT 0x80010202 exception
            }
            return null;
        }
            Where could be a problem?
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looked ok to me.

I did simplify it a bit so I could run it to as an add-in Button and it worked fine in 10.2.2.  You will be able to run this on two layers, The first layer in the Map will need to have a field called ID, and the Second layer needs a feature with OID 5 as written.

What line is the code failing on?

```
public class Button1 : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
{
    public Button1()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {

        TestMethod();

        ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = null;
    }
    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        Enabled = ArcMap.Application != null;
    }
    private void TestMethod() {
        try
        {
            IMxDocument mxd = ArcMap.Document;
            ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilter();

            IQueryFilter qFilter = new QueryFilterClass() { WhereClause = string.Format("{0} IS NOT NULL", "ID") };
            ILayer foundLayer = mxd.FocusMap.get_Layer(0);
            IFeatureLayer layer2 = (IFeatureLayer)mxd.FocusMap.get_Layer(1);
            spatialFilter.Geometry = layer2.FeatureClass.GetFeature(5).Shape;

            IFeatureCursor featureCursor = (foundLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer).Search(qFilter, false);
            IFeature feature;

            List<DistanceTest> _list = new List<DistanceTest>();

            while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
            {
                double distance = ((IProximityOperator)spatialFilter.Geometry).ReturnDistance(feature.Shape);
                IProximityOperator prox = spatialFilter.Geometry as IProximityOperator;
                distance = prox.ReturnDistance(feature.Shape);
                //Simplified to Prove concept
                if (distance > 0)
                {

                     var one = feature.get_Value(feature.Fields.FindField("ID")); // StreetsName = "STR_NAME"

                     _list.Add(new DistanceTest(feature.OID, distance));


                }
            }
   foreach (var _dist in _list)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID: {0} Distance: {1}", _dist.ID.ToString(), _dist.Distance.ToString());
        }     }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); 
        }


        return;
    }
    private class DistanceTest {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Double Distance { get; set; }

        public DistanceTest(int _id, double _distance) {
            this.ID = _id;
            Distance = _distance;
        }
    }
}
```